# localhost 500 internal server error

Tags: apache2, localhost

localhost 500 internal server error.

```
root@kumar-desktop:/# sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]
```

am searching lot of things but no result..

Comment: What is a "lot of things"?

Comment: am following this steps : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting_Apache  but no result

Comment: The congregation at this server message is that it is so unspecific. Since theoretically could be just "Something is going wrong!" – When immersed in this message? Which request you have sent to the server.

Comment: What is in the log files?

Comment: yes. log details.

Comment: How to solve it?

Comment: Worked the server before?

Comment: yes. Worked the server

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy apache2`

Comment: Have you changed the configuration, have you added something? Give more information.

Comment: change the server name localhost.

Comment: Revert the changes and restart  your server.

Comment: run the command      :   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf and  put "servername localhost" and save it.

Comment: Remove the configuration and try it again

Comment: ok .  remove the server name and try it..

Comment: one doubt, reinstall apache2 means lose the www folder content or not.

Comment: No, you don't lose the folder. `sudo apt-get purge apache2; sudo apt-get install apache2`. You could rename the folder to be sure. And rename the folder `/etc/apache2` to protect your configurations.

Comment: And? Are you done? Problem solved?

Comment: running the command : sudo service apache2 start    but got the error..

Comment: * Starting web server apache2                                                   * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin`

Comment: @A.B. Ok try it.

Comment: and command the line #LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so

Comment: running the command in terminal : sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: Got the message :  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: and localhost 404 not found error

Comment: Point 6 in my answer

Comment: got it. display the message : * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: With the entry in `fqdn.conf`?

Comment: You **could** set the `ServerName` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. But I believe, that's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok A.B.  How to link /var/www to /home/kumar/www/html

Comment: Running this command :  sudo ln -s /home/kumar/www/html /var/www

Comment: But the message : ln: failed to create symbolic link `/var/www/html': File exists

Comment: How to working localhost?

Comment: Sorry, be fair. That's a completely different question and has nothing to do with your error 500. **;)**

Comment: localhost 403 forbidden error display

Comment: @A.B.  Great. working fine. Thanks for your great support and save my times. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The congregation at this server message is that it is so unspecific. Since theoretically could be just *Something is going wrong!*

1. Remove the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf` via

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf.bak
   ```

   and unlink the configuration

   ```
   sudo a2disconf fqdn
   ```
2. Restart your server and check if the problem is solved

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
3. If not, backup your configurations and install apache2 again via

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/apache2 /etc/apache2.bak
   sudo apt-get purge apache2
   sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
4. Restart your server and check if the problem is solved

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
5. If you get a error message like

   ```
   The apache2 configtest failed. Output of config test was: apache2:
   Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error
   on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: Cannot load
   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2
   modules/mod_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
   directory Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have
   more information.
   ```

   reinstall `apache2-bin` via

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin
   ```

   because the file `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so` is part of the package `apache2-bin`
6. And now again

   ```
   echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
   sudo a2enconf fqdn
   ```